# Why is variance defined as the expected value of difference squared?

Tags: statistics

As I understand it, variance of a random variable is defined as follows: 
\begin{equation}
\text{Var}(X) = \text{E}[(X-\mu)^2]
\end{equation} 
$X-\mu$ is obviously the difference between the value of the random variable and the expected value of the random variable.

Why don't we define variance as 
\begin{equation}
\text{Var}(X) = \text{E}[X-\mu]
\end{equation}

To me, this would make more sense because it would express the difference between the expected value and the value it takes...which to me sounds like variation.

Why do we use the $(X-\mu)^2$ instead?

Comment: On the right side of this page, under Related, you will find the question why the definition of variance is such. That (and the duplicates pointed to) will answer your question.

Comment: $E[X-\mu]$ is always $0$, so it does not express anything about $X$.

Comment: I think I have received enough help I am satisfied. Thanks